# XSS - is it dangerous that innerText string can be HTML elements: script, div etc?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm working on the client side of a reviews web site.

the user can insert in the review description, any text including html element text (like : `<script> console.log('hello') </script>`), and style it with the basic text styles: italic, bold etc...

I wanted to test cross site scripting. so i played with it a little,  and when using italic the elements get rendered as the innerText of the html element.

The innerText in the HTML looked like this:

[image: html with script element and DOM js]

I didn't saw the alert get executed, though.

can the user write text that will become valid HTML with it's events invoked ?
if so, how ?

Comment: Note: For your img pen-test it should be `<img onerror="alert('test');" src="">`. `onload` wouldn't fire here even on insecure setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing in the elements/DOM tab is misleading you a bit. If you've used [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) (or more appropriately [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), usually) to set the text of an element, it **doesn't** have tags in it. It has characters. Those characters can form tags from a display perspective, but they aren't tags and the browser doesn't treat them that way.

One way to see this is to see the HTML for them:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");
target.textContent =
    `<script>alert("Hi!");<\/script>
    <div onclick='alert("Ho!");'>click me</div>
    <img onerror='alert("Hum!");' src=''>`;
console.log("textContent:", target.textContent);
console.log("innerHTML:", target.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Notice that the element doesn't contain a `script` tag, it contains the characters `<`, `s`, `c`, `r`, `i`, `p`, `t`, etc.

---

**In contrast**, using `innerHTML` leaves you wide open to XSS attacks:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");
target.innerHTML =
    `<script>alert("Hi!");<\/script>
    <div onclick='alert("Ho!");'>click me</div>
    <img onerror='alert("Hum!");' src=''>`;
console.log("textContent:", target.textContent);
console.log("innerHTML:", target.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

`script` tags inserted that way don't get run, but attribute-defined event handlers do, such as the `error` event on an `img` that has no `src` — and the code that *that* runs could add a `script` that would get executed:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");
target.innerHTML =
    `<div onclick='alert("Ho!");'>click me</div>
    <img onerror='(function() {
        alert("Hi!");
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.textContent = &apos;alert("Hi from script");&apos;;
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    })()' src=''>`;
console.log("textContent:", target.textContent);
console.log("innerHTML:", target.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: hey, thx for the explanation. if you don't mind i have a follow-up question. I use react with dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop, on a div, to handle this elements. if it's not dangerous, why doe's it label that way ?  link to docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: @ItayTur - It ***is*** dangerous! :-) `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` sets **`innerHTML`**, not `textContent` or `innerText`. That's a Whole Different Thing. You asked about `innerText`, not `innerHTML`. **Do not** use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to add user-supplied content to the page (unless you only show the content to the user that supplied it, not to other users; and even then, it's usually not best practice).